# Issues returning multiple values in crawling script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my current code. The time portion is working great, the distance portion seems to be working well as well, but the heart rate portion is a bit wonky still.

I am unsure how to return two separate values from the function. I guess it needs two separate arguments then? I tried "return x and y", but it didn't work very well.

If I can return two values, I should also be able to extract two values which would make the script a lot less clunky, because then I won't have to search for the same activity multiple times.

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import login as login
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import datetime
import time

x = datetime.datetime.now()
x = x.strftime("%b %d")

driver = browser = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1512, 1000)
driver.get("https://connect.garmin.com/modern/activities")

driver.implicitly_wait(1)

iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, "gauth-widget-frame-gauth-widget")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element("name", "username").send_keys(login.username)

driver.find_element("name", "password").send_keys(login.password)
driver.find_element("name", "password").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.switch_to.default_content()

time.sleep(10)

def get_time_xpath(value):
    return "//span[text() = '{}']//ancestor::div[@class='list-item-container']//div[5]//div[2]//span//span[1]".format(value)

def get_distance_xpath(value):
    return "//span[text() = '{}']//ancestor::div[@class='list-item-container']//div[5]//div[1]//span//span[1]".format(value)

def get_hr_xpath(arg):
    return "//span[text() = '{}']//ancestor::div[@class='list-item-container']//div[5]//div[4]//span//span".format(arg)


distance_str = get_distance_xpath(x)

date_str = get_time_xpath(x)

hr_str = get_hr_xpath(x)


# def get_time_from_page(activity):
# 
#   time.sleep(2)
# 
#   driver.find_element("name", "search").clear()
#   driver.find_element("name", "search").send_keys(activity)
#   driver.find_element("name", "search").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# 
#   time.sleep(3)
#   result_1 = 0
#   current_time = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, date_str)
# 
#   for times in current_time:
#       if len(times.text) >= 7:
#           result = time.strptime(times.text, "%H:%M:%S")
#           result_1 += result.tm_hour * 60
#           result_1 += result.tm_min
#       else:
#           result = time.strptime(times.text, "%M:%S")
#           result_1 += result.tm_min
# 
#   return result_1


def get_distance_and_hr(activity):

    time.sleep(2)

    driver.find_element("name", "search").clear()
    driver.find_element("name", "search").send_keys(activity)
    driver.find_element("name", "search").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    time.sleep(3)
    result_2 = 0.00
    hr_value = 0
    distance = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, distance_str)
    heart_rate = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, hr_str)

    for dist in distance:
        remove = float(dist.text.rstrip(" km"))
        result_2 += remove

    for val in heart_rate:
        reduce = float(val.text.rstrip(" bpm"))
        hr_value += reduce

    return result_2 and hr_value



# time_read = get_time_from_page("Reading")
# time_meditated = get_time_from_page("Meditation")
# time_programmed = get_time_from_page("Programming")
# time_walked = get_time_from_page("Walking")
# time_running = get_time_from_page("Running")
distance_walked = get_distance_and_hr("Walking")
heart_rate_walk = get_distance_and_hr("Walking")

# print(time_read)
# print(time_meditated)
# print(time_programmed)
# print(time_walked)
# print(time_running)
print(f"Distance walked today is {distance_walked} km and average BPM is {heart_rate_walk}") ```
````

Comment: Where you are struggling? What it should do, what it is coming?

Answer (score 0):

when you return `value1 and value 2` the function will return only the last value.

Instead, when you have multiple items to return you can return them in a tuple and extract them from it.

### You can try doing:

```
return result_2, hr_value

#or

return (result_2, hr_value)

#or 

return tuple(result_2, hr_value)
```